# How to set null value for a column in table through spring boot JPA

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot, jpa

How to set null value for a column in table through spring boot JPA.

I have some requirement where I need to set null to all the records in table.

IN My repository I have written

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query("update table_name set column_name = null")
void setNull();
```

In My service I have written

`myRepository.rsetNull();`

But for running this I am getting error like this.

**Caused by: org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract void**

Comment: @kerbermeister same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason is that you wrote a **native query** in your `@Query` annotation, but `@Query` annotation by default works with `JPQL` queries, not with native.

As docs from `@Query` annotation suggests:

> /**    Configures whether the given query is a native one. Defaults
> to {@literal false}.   */     boolean nativeQuery() default false;

So, from perspective of `JPQL` you work with **domains**, not with **tables**.

With JPQL your query would look like:

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query("update Domain d set d.fieldName = null")
```

If you want to use native query, then you should specify the flag `nativeQuery = true`

So, your native query would like:

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query(value = "update table_name set column_name = null", nativeQuery = true)
```